# Custom UUID field PK returns wrong type when accessed as a foreign key

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I need a UUID pk and due to some serialization issues I was thinking about making it a UUID only in the DB and a string outside of it.

I've created this custom field that allows exactly that.

```
import uuid
from typing import Union

from django.db import models


class CustomUUIDField(models.UUIDField):
    """
    In database: uuid
    Outside of a database: str
    """
    description = "Custom UUID field which is an UUID only in DB and a string outside of it"

    @staticmethod
    def _serialize_value(value: Union[str, uuid.UUID]) -> str:
        return str(value)

    @staticmethod
    def _deserialize_value(value: Union[str, uuid.UUID]) -> uuid.UUID:
        if isinstance(value, str):
            value = uuid.UUID(value, version=4)
        return value

    def to_python(self, value) -> str:
        return self._serialize_value(value)

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection) -> str:
        return self._serialize_value(value)

    def get_prep_value(self, value) -> str:
        return self._serialize_value(value)

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        value = self.value_from_object(obj)
        return self.get_prep_value(value)

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False) -> uuid.UUID:
        return self._deserialize_value(value)


class UUIDMixin(models.Model):
    id = CustomUUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def is_new(self) -> bool:
        return self._state.adding

    def __str__(self):
        return f"<{self.__class__.__qualname__}: {self.id}>"
```

Now I have these two fellas

```
class A(UUIDMixin):
    pass


class B(UUIDMixin):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What is inconsistent is that:

`a.id` returns a string.
`b.id` returns a string.
`b.a.id` returns a UUID

Did I forget to override a method in my custom field? Is the behavior I'd expect even doable without some nasty hacks?

Django 3.0.8.

EDIT: I don't think it's doable. I abandon this idea and use UUIDs as intended.

EDIT 2: There are two things I want to add here.

I tried with

```
@CustomUUIDField.register_lookup
class IDCase(Transform):
    lookup_name = 'id'
    function = 'CAST'
    bilateral = True

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        sql, params = compiler.compile(self.lhs)
        sql = 'CAST(%s AS TEXT)' % sql
        return sql, params

    @property
    def output_field(self):
        return CharField()
```

and it didn't work either.

Also, the example is not exactly correct. I think if you fetch data like that it works properly. But in Auth Middleware if I do `request.user.company.id` then it's UUID so it has to depend on how query is constructed by the ORM.